# pipenv not working after Mac OS Catalina update err: 'original_python' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, macos-catalina, pipenv

I am trying to use pipenv as follows

```
pipenv install dash==1.17.0
```

and getting  a selection of errors including

```
Creating virtual environment...Using base prefix '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8'

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'original_python' referenced before assignment

Failed to create virtual environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

This Github issue posting answered it

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4191

We need to add the --python parameter to the call so

```
pipenv install --python /usr/bin/python dash==1.17.0
```

Now it works as before.